# Getting prompted for a password via SSH even after setting up authorized_keys

Tags: permissions, ssh, password, amazon

Using Amazon Linux.  Just added a user, rebooted the machine, but still am getting prompted for a password when that user tries to SSH into the machine.  We have veriffied that the authorized_keys are set up with perrmissions outlined here -- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication, The permissions for the ~/.ssh directory from the client machine (also Amazon Linux) are as such:

```
drwx------ 2 couser cogroup 4096 Mar 22 14:53 .
drwx------ 3 couser cogroup 4096 Mar 22 14:44 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 couser cogroup  255 Mar 22 14:46 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 couser cogroup  887 Mar 22 14:53 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 couser cogroup  243 Mar 22 14:53 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 couser cogroup 1332 Mar 21 15:30 known_hosts
```

then on the remote machine the permissions on the ~/.ssh are

```
[adminuser@remotemachine ~]$ sudo ls -al /home/couser/.ssh
total 12
drwx------ 2 couser cogroup  4096 Mar 22 14:58 .
drwx------ 3 couser couser 4096 Mar 22 14:54 ..
-rw------- 1 couser cogroup   499 Mar 22 14:58 authorized_keys
```

Is there any other setting I need to enable for the user to allow them to SSH into the remote machine without being prompted for a password?

Comment: can you confirm that the `authorized_keys` on the remote machine holds the content of the `id_rsa.pub` from the client machine?

Comment: are you able to login into the remote machine (using password), and check the content of the file, to make sure that it actually includes your public key?

Comment: Post the verbose log from the connection, have a look to the errors on the server.

Comment: @Yaron, I'm not able to login on the remote machine using a password.  What does that mean?

Comment: You did not write that your keys were generated without passphrase, but I guess you did. If not that would be the reason. Other your password is likely the login password of the target system, that would be standard behaviour. There is a setting - I believe in openssh server - that password authorizsation is set to "no". If you are connected to the internet be very careful that your key setup is 1000%, because SSH is the major target around the clock. I am sorry that I can not give the exact location of the setting, But I am quite sure its documented in the Ubuntu Wiki page for OpenSSH server.

Answer (score 0):

K, turned out the solution was to add the username to the

```
AllowUsers
```

line of the

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

file.